# Format and unformat numbers in jquery

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

I format numbers using jqnumformatter plugin. Everything is fine with that but I'm having problems on removing the commas. I used .each() to loop through all the inputs which has commas on it. But in this case I need to click on the next button twice so that all the commas on the numbers will be removed.

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $("#next").click(function(){//unformats the numbers

        $("input[data-toformat=format]").each(function(){
            var formatted = $(this).val();
            var unformatted = formatted.replace(",", "");
            $(this).val(unformatted);
        });

    });


});
</script>

<input type="text" id="num" data-toformat="format"  autofocus/>
<input type="text" id="num2" data-toformat="format" />
<input type="button" id="next" value="next">
<input type="button" id="back" value="back">
```

Do you have a better way on doing this?It really fails to unformat the numbers all at once if I have 2 or more commas on each of the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are calling the [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var unformatted = formatted.replace(",", "");
```

If you pass a string as the first parameter it only replaces the first occurrence. If you pass a regular expression you can set the regex "global" flag to replace all occurrences:

```
var unformatted = formatted.replace(/,/g, "");
```

Note that your code can be simplified quite a bit because you don't really need the local variables:

```
$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/,/g, "") );
```

But it can be simplified even further because if you pass a function to the [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) you don't even need the `.each()` loop:

```
$(function(){
   $("#next").click(function(){
       //unformats the numbers
       $("input[data-toformat=format]").val(function(i, oldVal){
           return oldVal.replace(/,/g, "");
       });
   });
});
```

This syntax for `.val()` will pass the old (current) value of each element to the function you supply, setting the new value to the return from that function.

Comment: Will _what_ work for dynamically generated elements? The `.replace()` part works on any string. The `.val()` part (or the `.each()` from your code) works on any elements in the jQuery object that you run it on, i.e., any elements that matched the selector at the time.